# How to implement a self-hosted WCF Service with JSON and documentation?

Tags: .net, json, wcf

I have a windows forms project that self-hosts a WCF service. It's been working for a while. The communication is by XML. However, now I need to use JSON. I've been reading and trying stuff for two days by now, with no luck.

So, I've started from this:

```
urlService = ("http://" & _ipAddress.ToString & "/mySvc") 
aManager = New mySvc 
host = New ServiceHost(aManager, New Uri(urlService))

Dim tBinding As BasicHttpBinding 
tBinding = New BasicHttpBinding() 
tBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None

host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(myInterface), tBinding, urlService)


Dim metadataBehavior As ServiceMetadataBehavior 
metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find(Of ServiceMetadataBehavior)()

If (metadataBehavior Is Nothing) Then   
    metadataBehavior = New ServiceMetadataBehavior  
    metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = New Uri(("http://" & _ipAddress.ToString & "/mySvcWSDL"))     
    metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = True  
    metadataBehavior.ToString()     
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior) 
End If

host.Open()
```

So, as I've understand, I can't use JSON with BasicHttpBinding, so I've tried switching the bindings to wsHTTPBinding and webHTTPBinding, and change some other settings in the endpoints or the behaviors. Sometimes the project runs, but it doesn't work. Sometimes the project won't start (something regarding the uritemplate decoration in the interface), sometimes the project starts but it doesn't works (HTTP ERROR 405 when I try to use the function), sometimes a strange error regarding ContractFilter and EndpointDispatcher, and so on.

Also, I've changed the decorations of my Interface:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface myInterface
    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/LeoTest1/{Param1}")>
    Function LeoTest1(Param1 As String) As String

End Interface
```

...and, of my manager class:

```
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults:=True, AddressFilterMode:=AddressFilterMode.Any)>
Public Class mySvc
...
```

Also, I don't know if it's regarding something wrong with my project or it's just the way it is, but with the XML endpoint I use SOAPUI to automatically create the  XML templates to use to communicate with my service. I'd like (need?) those templates for the JSON protocol too... it is possible? Must I add something else to the host? Can't do that with SOAPUI, and I do need another tool?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried the steps below?

1. Add a reference to the System.ServiceModel.Web framework
2. Update the app.config file with the lines below:

```html
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="YourServiceName">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:YourPort/service1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="YourServiceName.IService1" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ServiceModel.Web was already added in my project. Also, I intended to run the host from the code, without the static XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's went on, but I've solved it by replacing the ServiceHost object for the WebServiceHost object.

I still have issues with some methods (one works, other don't) but I think that it isn't related with this.

Regards,